# csv rearrange the data in a readable way

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file with tons of data and each piece of data is stored in a dictionary i need it in a readable format e.g.

```
 id     name    product   temperature   density   timestamp   water
 1       1001     14         30          40         40         40  
 2       1002     14         30          50         50         50
```

i would like these headers only when ive tried it keeps the whole data and doesn't format it here is the data file i hope you guys can help with this: 
p.s sorry about the amount of data

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qdcl2lrrqj6sttb/AABo_AMGzFqetgRne_7XTPy7a?dl=0

currently ive tried 
    def funcScript():

```
from data import tankOBJ as tank
with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/csv tester/motherwell.csv')),'r',newline='') as output_file:
    fieldnames = ['id','name','product','temperature','density','timestamp','water']

    writer = csv.Dictwriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()


    for line in csv_reader:
    del line['shortname','state','shape','pos_x','pos_y','datum',',max_work','min_work','offset_bottom','offset_volume','offset_level','roof_density','roof_weight','roof_start','roof_end','shell_insulated','shell_cte','shell_temperature','dimension_a','dimension_b','dimension_c','dimension_d','knee_forth','knee_third','knee_second','knee_first','suction_forth,','suction_third','suction_second','suction_first','rundown_forth','rundown_third','rundown_second','rundown_first','suction_low_forth','suction_low_third','suction_low_second','suction_low_first','rundown_low_forth','rundown_low_third','rundown_low_second','rundown_low_first','sll','slu','svl','suv','swlv','swuv','swll','swul','volume','innage','flow','pressure','maximum_volume',]
    writer.writerow(tank)




    return 'Hello World!'
```

basically ive ripped the data from another file and got it to download off my webapp in csv format which gives live readings

Comment: It seems there is no actual data download link.

Comment: You need to show us the code you have tried so far. Also, please give an example of the data dictionary.

Comment: ive link you the data file on dropbox

Comment: ok  thats what ive done so far